# Structural types with generics in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, structural-typing, scala-generics

I tried to define a structural type which is matched to an instance with a generic type. Like in this example code:

```
class ExampleTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  def add[T](container: {def add(s: T): Boolean})(element: T): Unit = {
    container.add(element)
  }

  val set = new java.util.HashSet[String]()
  add(set)("3")
  set.contains("3") shouldEqual true

  val list = new java.util.LinkedList[String]()
  add(list)("3")
  list.contains("3") shouldEqual true
}
```

but I get a compilation error:

`Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to an abstract type defined outside that refinement
   def add[T](container: {def add(s: T): Boolean})(element: T): Unit = {`

When I get rid of the generic type in the method and write the code like this:

```
class ExampleTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  def add(container: {def add(s: String): Boolean}): Unit = {
    container.add("3")
  }

  val set = new java.util.HashSet[String]()
  add(set)
  set.contains("3") shouldEqual true

  val list = new java.util.LinkedList[String]()
  add(list)
  list.contains("3") shouldEqual true
}
```

it compiles but I get a runtime exception:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.HashSet.add(java.lang.String)`

My question is:
How to correctly define the structural type, so it can work with Java collections?

Note that it cannot replace them with Scala collection (it will be used with a Java library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls

def add[T](container: {def add(s: Any): Boolean})(element: T): Unit = {
  container.add(element)
}

val set = new java.util.HashSet[String]()
add(set.asInstanceOf[{def add(s: Any): Boolean}])("3")
set.contains("3") shouldEqual true

val list = new java.util.LinkedList[String]()
add(list.asInstanceOf[{def add(s: Any): Boolean}])("3")
list.contains("3") shouldEqual true
```

Signature for `java.util.HashSet#add` (actually `java.util.AbstractCollection#add`) and `java.util.LinkedList#add` is

```
boolean add(E e)
```

Reflective calls for structural types are resolved at runtime. At runtime because of type erasure generic `E` is just `Any` (aka `Object`).

More details: [Structural types with generic type](http://www.scala-archive.org/scala-Structural-types-with-generic-type-question-td1992248.html)